How to reference many raster layers in the lapp function of {terra} in R
I am attempting to create rasters with estimates of extraterrestrial radiation as outlined by the FAO Irrigation and Drainage paper 56. It only depends on julian day and latitude, and its calculation is relatively straightforward:
# steps for estimating extraterrestrial radiation
# https://www.fao.org/3/x0490e/x0490e07.htm#radiation
# depends on day of year and latitude

# create vector of julian days and a latitude point
jday <- 1:366
lat <- -22.5

# inverse relative distance Earth-Sun (Equation 23)
dr <- 1 + (0.033 * cos(2*pi/365*jday))

# solar declination (Equation 24)
d <- 0.409 * sin(2*pi*(jday)/365 - 1.39)

# sunset hour angle (Equation 25)
ws <- acos(-tan(lat*pi/180) * tan(d))

# extraterrestrial radiation (Equation 21)
Ra <- (24*60/pi) * 0.0820 * dr * (ws * sin(lat*pi/180) * sin(d) + cos(lat*pi/180) * cos(d) * sin(ws))

However, I would like to wrap up these calculations in a function and apply it on a spatial object, so I can have a map of extraterrestrial radiation.
In order to do so, I have create raster of latitudes and 366 layers where each layer would be a 'julian day':
library(terra)

# create toy raster
r <- rast(nrow=420, ncol=440, xmin=-75.95, xmax=-31.95, ymin=-35.05, ymax=6.95)

# re-create raster only with latitudes
r <- init(r, 'y')
plot(r)

# replicate 366 layers, simulating one raster per julian day
r <- rep(r, 366)
names(r) <- 1:nlyr(r)

It seems like lapp should do what I am looking for, where each pixel has a value of lat and each layer is a jday in the previous example.
However, it looks like lapp needs each layer as an argument of the function. Since there are 366 layers, it seems really unpractical to explicitly reference each of them.
What would be the correct way to use terra::lapp for this case? Is there any other terra function that I could use?

One thing I learned last year when starting with FAO-56 and arriving at Meeus (1998) after some time: day of year (doy) != julian date (jd) != julian day number (jdn).

No need to create a 366 layers raster, unless you want to combine two different datasets. Just take the latitude raster and iterate through it.
For example, using a library I'm building (it's still in beta phase) for managing agricultural data:
library(terra)
library(agrtools)

r <- rast(nrow=420, ncol=440, xmin=-75.95, xmax=-31.95, ymin=-35.05, ymax=6.95)
r <- init(r, 'y')

# convert degree to radians
rad = app(r, function(x) convert_units(x, "angle", "deg", "rad") )
# iterate to compute extraterrestrial radiation
re = rast(mapply(function(x) app(rad, extraterrestrial_radiation, j=x), 1:366))
# add appropriate names
names(re) = paste0('day', 1:366)


Neat! Such a coincidence that we were working on the same topic at the same time. Thanks for your package, it looks like a really useful one for agrometeorology researchers.
